# Checkboxes moving on float:right

Tags: javascript, css, html, checkbox

I've been having this issue for the past few days. I am attempting to move my checkboxes to the right side of the pane in my window. But, whenever I use float:right to move them they also move down about 20-30px, which means they are no longer properly lined up with their labels.

Here is the code for the pane with the labels/images/checkboxes that I want to all be aligned:

```
<div id="leftPane" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left'">

            <div id="sealDiv" style="padding-top:0px;vertical-align:middle;"><a href="http://google.com"><img src="images/seal.png" alt="countySeal" style="width:150px;height:150px; "/></a></div>

            <h3 style="vertical-align:middle;"><u> Live Layers </u></h3>
            <div id="layerLabels">
            <img src="images/stateParkIcon.png" alt="stateParksIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>State Parks <input id="stateParks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="stateChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/countyParksIcon.png" alt="countyParksIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px;"/> <label>County Parks <input id="countyParks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="countyChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/countyOpenSpaceIcon.png" alt="countyOpenSpaceIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>County Open Spaces <input id="countyOpenSpace" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="countyOpenChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/localParksIcon.png" alt="localParksIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Local Parks <input id="localParks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="localChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/golfCourse.png" alt="imgGolf" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Golf Courses <input id="golfCourses" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="golfCoursesChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/beach.png" alt="imgBeach" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Beaches <input id="beaches" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="beachesChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/iceRink.png" alt="imgIce" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Ice Rinks <input id="iceRinks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="iceRinksChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/swimming.png" alt="imgSwim" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Indoor Pools <input id="indoorPools" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="indoorPoolsChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/campgrounds.png" alt="imgCamp" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Campgrounds <input id="campgrounds" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="campgroundsChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/boatLaunches.png" alt="imgBoat" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Boat Launches <input id="boatLaunches" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="boatLaunchesChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/marinas.png" alt="imgMarinas" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Marinas <input id="marinas" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="marinasChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/playgrounds.png" alt="imgPlaygronds" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Playgrounds <input id="playgrounds" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="playgroundsChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/bikepath.png" alt="imgBike" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Bike Paths <input id="bikePaths" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="bikePathsChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/boardwalksIcon.png" alt="boardwalkIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Boardwalks <input id="boardwalks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="boardwalksChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/hikingIcon.png" alt="hikingIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Hiking Trails <input id="hikingTrails" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="hikingTrailsChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/crosswalksIcon.png" alt="crosswalksIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px"/> <label>Crosswalks <input id="crosswalks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="crosswalksChanged()"></label>
            <br/>
            <img src="images/sidewalksIcon.png" alt="sidewalkIcon" style="height:20px; width:20px;"/> <label>Sidewalks <input id="sidewalks" class="lyrCB" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" onChange="sidewalksChanged()"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a "quick fix" to this, either CSS or Javasript OR have I created the pane in such a way that it needs to be redone to work properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you update your question to include normal checkbox inputs and not dojo stuff?

Comment: I don't see why that is important? I'm fairly new to this all so if there is some sort of CSS or javascript affecting the position based on the dojo or normal (type="checkbox") then please let me know. Otherwise it would all be the same except the imagery of the boxes as well as how I call the functions, but I want it working with these because I am using dojo checkbox CSS for appearance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options here, but essentially it's being pushed down by the other elements that are not floated.

1. Float the other elements as well.
2. Put the checkbox first in the HTML (before image and label).
3. Use absolute positioning instead.

Comment: Moving them in front of the image and label did the trick! I forgot floated elements need to be before non-floated. Thanks!